# Does the bonus from the Great Lighthouse stack with England's bonus

Tags: civilization-5

England gets a civ bonus +1 movement for naval units

The Great Lighthouse gives a +1 movement bonus for naval units

Does this stack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. There's no real reason it shouldn't stack in the first place. England makes it easy to get triremes with 7 movement, which is sorta ridiculous.

Comment: those are some skilled sailors

Comment: It gets better -- upgrading them to frigates, and then destroyers, they stack the +sight upgrade, so you've got 8 vision as well. SURPRISE! Naval invasion from halfway across the map!

Comment: what's even better is imho is the bonuses on embarked troops, much less chance of your army being sunk while crossing an ocean if they are only on the water 1 turn